# PHP - How to remove this undefined array index with list

Tags: php, arrays, phplist

I have the following code on my page:

```
if (variable_get('ds_extras_fields_extra')) {
    $fields = explode("\n", variable_get('ds_extras_fields_extra_list', FALSE));
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
      $field = trim($field);
      if (!empty($field)) {
        list($entity, $bundle, $field_name) = explode('|', $field);
        $extra[check_plain($entity)][check_plain($bundle)]['display'][$field_name] = array(
          'label' => drupal_ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', check_plain($field_name))),
          'description' => drupal_ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', check_plain($field_name))),
          'weight' => 0,
        );
      }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an undefined error randomly that occurs as a PHP Notice on the page, I just want to not see this error anymore... Preferrably, I can fix undefined errors by just checking `isset()`, but not sure how to do it on a php `list` language construct.

The error occurs on this line here:

```
list($entity, $bundle, $field_name) = explode('|', $field);
```

And shows as follows:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in ds_extras_field_extra_fields() (line
>   514 of /sites/all/modules/ds/modules/ds_extras/ds_extras.module).

Comment: `if (isset(variable_get('ds_extras_fields_extra'))) {`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `variable_get` function.  It is being used millions of times and works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about error_reporting or the @ instructor? http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.errors.php

Only suggested as you do not want to change anything. I do not suggest to actually use it, just fix your issue:)

Comment: Don't want to disable error_reporting for now.  But where could I put the `@` instructor exactly so as to remove the error notice?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of this originally.  Works like a charm!

Comment: I strongly advice **not** to use the suppressor `@`. Instead focus on finding the real problem.

Comment: Don't we all want to find the real problem? The fact is, I don't have 5 months to search through and try to understand 50 billion lines of code (that took years to create from multiple people) that all tie into each other at over 20 different PHP pages, just to hunt down a **random** PHP undefined Notice.  This is when Priorities take over and time disallows!

Comment: And that's how these problems are made :)

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct and I DO advice him not to use it!

Comment: @StijnvanGrinsven - Thanks for your answer, it was most helpful, so I gave you a +1 as well, just now, making the count at 0.  Honestly, I appreciate a straightforward answer and also appreciate the warning as well.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_NOTICE ^E_WARNING);

You can try at the top of your script. it will disable all notifications and warning.